# How to draw 2D circle in irrlicht

Tags: graphics, drawing, 2d, irrlicht

Is there a way to draw a simple circle with given radius and center point in irrlicht?

Answer (score 0):

You can use driver->[draw2DPolygon()](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1video_1_1_i_video_driver.html#aaf1318379f3d70c9347cfa853b944ad4) method.
Simply pass **vertexCount** to be high enough for your size of shape (the smaller circle on the screen, the lower value you can pass and it won't be noticeable that it has edges).